# Rename file 20140914_foo.pdf to 2014-09-14 Sunday.pdf

Tags: file, powershell, rename

I've got a directory with newspapers:

```
20140914_foo.pdf
20140915_foo.pdf
20140916_foo.pdf
```

And I want to rename them to

```
2014-09-14 Sunday.pdf
2014-09-15 Monday.pdf
2014-09-16 Tuesday.pdf
```

These two statements do the trick:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Insert(4,'-').Insert(7,'-') -replace 'foo', ''}
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName + ' ' + (get-date($_.BaseName)).DayOfWeek + $_.Extension}
```

Is there an elegant way to do it in one statement?

Comment: The expression in braces is a scriptblock so can contain several statements. Extract the date and day to temporary variables, build up the new name and then just return that as a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EDIT: Added Frode's suggestion

Try this, the code will split the filename, parse the date string as `[datetime]` type and extract its properties to build the required name:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem | % {
    $date = [datetime]::ParseExact(($_.Name -split "_")[0],"yyyyMMdd",$null)
    $newName = "$($date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) $($date.DayOfWeek).pdf"
    ren $_ $newName
}
```

Comment: I would use `$newname = "$($date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))_$($date.DayOfWeek).pdf"` to clean up the scriptblock :)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go - one line:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_[^.]+(\.\w+)', "`$1-`$2-`$3 $([DateTime]::ParseExact(($_.BaseName -split '_')[0], 'yyyyMMdd',$null).DayOfWeek)`$4"} -WhatIf

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Keith\20140914_foo.pdf
Destination: C:\Users\Keith\2014-09-14 Sunday.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Keith\20140915_foo.pdf 
Destination: C:\Users\Keith\2014-09-15 Monday.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Keith\20140916_foo.pdf
Destination: C:\Users\Keith\2014-09-16 Tuesday.pdf".
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` to do the actual renaming.  The approach above uses capture groups to capture the year, month, day and extension from the filename.  It then parses the capture groups for year, month, day into a DateTime object so we can get the day of week.